# C#. Как получить данные введенные в TextBox

Tags: c#, gui

Только начинаю. Предположим пользователь вводит уравнение в TextBox, как мне получить данные из введенного уравнения?

Comment: давайте на конкретных примерах. Как вы строите форму? Что именно южзер вводит? Что именно из его ввода вам надо получить? И самое главное, как вы сами пытались вашу задачу решить и что не получилось?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string txbValue = TextBox.Text ;
```